# Spread Polynomials Identity (Rational Trigonometry)

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, binomial-coefficients, combinations

**Show that if $ n=2l+1 $ is an odd natural number then** $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)=s\left( \binom{n}{1}\left( 1-s \right)^{l}-\binom{n}{3}\left( 1-s \right)^{l-1}s+\binom{n}{5}\left( 1-s \right)^{l-2}s^{2}-\cdots+(-1)^{l}s^{l} \right)^{2} $$
(Exercise 8.7 on page 107 of N J Wildberger's book *Divine Proportions*.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Spread_polynomials
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html

First let us review our tools:

1. **Define the Spread Polynomials by a recursive 
   relation**:$$ S_{n+1}\left( s \right)= 2 \left(1-2s\right)S_{n}\left( s \right)-S_{n-1}\left( s \right)+2s $$ with $ S_0\left( s \right)=0 $ and $ S_1\left( s \right)=s $.
2. **Theorem 57 on page 106**: suppose that $ 4s(1-s)=r^{2} $ and that the field contains a number $ i $ such that $ i^2=-1 $. Then for any $ n=0,1,2,\ldots $ $$ S_{n} \left( s \right)=\frac{2-\left(1-2s+ir\right)^{n}-\left(1-2s-ir\right)^{n}}{4} $$

I used the classical trigonometric analogues (see above links) in two different ways to verify that what I want to show is indeed an identity. Unfortunately I could not find an analogous way of proving it, beacuse I want to completely avoid using square roots (except sqaure roots of square expressions), as is appropriate in Rational Trigonometry. In fact, the third of the explicit formulas shown in the wikipedia page is problematic in this regard.

Now denote $ 1-2s+ir=C $ and $ 1-2s-ir=D $. I used two methods to get $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)=s\left(\frac{C^l}{D-1}+\frac{D^l}{C-1} \right)^{2} $$
or $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)= -\frac{1}{4(1-s)} \left(\frac{C^{l+1}-D^{l+1}+C^{l}-D^{l}}{2} \right)^{2} $$ where you can factor $ \left(ir \right)^{2} $ to obtain the $ S_{n}\left( s \right)=s \left(\cdots \right)^{2} $ form.

In any case, I am having trouble dealing with the trinomial expensions of $ C $ and $ D $, whether I apply the binomial theorem twice to get cumbersome double sums or use the trinomial theorem directly to get alien coefficients.

There is a lot of manipulation that can be done; observe that $ C \cdot D=1 $ or that both $ S_{n+1}\left( s \right) $ and $ S_{n-1}\left( s \right) $ are squares or that $ 2-C^{n}-D^{n}=\left( 1-C^{n} \right)+\left( 1-D^{n} \right)=\left( 1-C^{n} \right) \cdot \left( 1-D^{n} \right) $ and so on.

I also want to avoid using generating functions in this stage.

*
*
*
EDIT: I think I am very close to solving this, but have a difficulty finishing up. The last obsticale is not related to Rational Trigonometry. I shall give my answer up until the problematic part in the following lines.

Check that what we want to show holds for $ s=1 $. Then for any $ s \neq 1 $ use tool #1 to obtain: $$ S_{n} \left( s \right)= -\frac{1}{4 \left( 1-s \right)} \left( -S_{n+1}\left( s \right)+2\left( -S_{s}\left( s \right)+s \right)+ \left( -S_{n-1}\left( s \right) \right) \right) $$
Then use tool #2 to obtain: $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)= -\frac{1}{4(1-s)} \left(\frac{C^{l+1}-D^{l+1}+C^{l}-D^{l}}{2} \right)^{2} $$ thus $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)= s \left(\frac{C \cdot C^{l}-D \cdot D^{l}+C^{l}-D^{l}}{2ir} \right)^{2} $$
Now observe that $ C=((1-s)-s)+ir $ and $ D=((1-s)-s)-ir $. Use the binomial theorem twice to obtain: $$ S_{n}\left( s \right)= s \left(\left( \sum_{k=0}^{l}{\sum_{m=0}^{l-k}{\binom{l}{k}\binom{l-k}{m}\left(1-s \right)^{l-k-m}s^{m}(-1)^{m}r^{k-1}i^{k-1} \left( \frac{2\left(1-s \right)-(-1)^{k}\left(2\left(1-s \right)\right)}{2} \right)}} \right)+\left( \sum_{k=0}^{l}{\sum_{m=0}^{l-k}{\binom{l}{k}\binom{l-k}{m}\left(1-s \right)^{l-k-m}s^{m}(-1)^{m}r^{k}i^{k} \left( \frac{1+(-1)^{k}}{2} \right)}} \right) \right)^{2} $$
So now my problem is to get from the above to what I want to show. I played a bit with even and odd $ k $s and the coefficients seem to add up, so I'm 97% sure the above is correct. Is there a cute way to finish this final transition?

Comment: For the sake of making this a bit more self-contained: the spread polynomials $S_n(s)$ are characterized by the equality $S_n(\sin^2\theta) = \sin^2(n\theta)$. In one sense they are trivially equivalent to the Chebyshev polynomials, but I wonder if something can be said about their factorizations that doesn't apply to Chebyshev polynomials. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Wildberger and Goh may have implied that there is on page 4 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1025.pdf , but that's all I found.